# local boolean variable doesn't obey inside the p-table from PrimeNG

Tags: angular

I just initialized a variable called `customDashboard: boolean = false` and after that, I called service and fetching some of the settings from the API server, and it returns an object with the value on it if it's true or false. and in the HTML template where I will use the condition if it matches and uses the template inside the prime ng's p-table. However, the condition doesn't obey the customDashboard variable

This is for an existing component where it was implementing a new p-table from prime ng component

```
<p-table ...... >
  <ng-template [ngIf]="customDashboard"><card-item></card-item></ng-template>
  <ng-template [ngIf]="!customDashboard"><table-base></table-base></ng-template>
</p-table>
```

But however if the value of customDashboard is true, it doesn't go to the card-item component but instead in the table-base, but when I insert the current value of the customDashboard inside the ng-template, it shows that it was true and it falls to the false condition.

Comment: Can you show where you change the customDashboard value?

Comment: @Jojofoulk inside the ngOnInit() with the service calling for a subscription and inside the result , there's a logic that would know the value from the request

Comment: If you could show exactly the part where you assign it would help narrow down the problem. You might not assign it correctly within your subscription.
Your template looks fine so I'd assume the problem comes somewhere from the .ts file

Comment: @Jojofoulk this is how it was written

ngOnInit() : {
  this.settingsService.subscribe(res => { this.customDashboard = res.value; }
}